# How to log Mac OS X graphics card driver

Tags: macos, graphics, driver

In my Mac OS X application, I would like to log the user's graphics card driver and model. What is the appropriate API to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not been able to find an API to find this information, but you can get some information about the display hardware by running the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType
```

Using `dtruss` that command appears to be doing something with executable code in `/System/Library/SystemProfiler/SPDisplaysReporter.spreporter/Contents/MacOS/SPDisplaysReporter`, but it's a bit hard to tell what exactly.

Comment: Use `system_profiler -xml SPDisplaysDataType` for nice XML output.

Comment: Thanks! 7654321 Halleluja! Joel minimum character limit reached! WTF! (Please ignore everything behind `Thanks!` or forward directly to Joel if you feel like it.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the the Graphics Card Driver and Model provided by `IORegistryExploer`, an application showing the hierarchies about the Devices and Drivers?

If so, you may use command `ioreg -l` in the terminal, and then filter the information you need.

Of course, how execute shell command in your application is another question, you may use the API provided by Cocoa, `NSTask`, or use the `system()` function.